# In node code, when I use "reques" ,response.timings is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I wrote this code in node.js, but **response.timing** is undefined.
Whats the problem with my cod>

```
const request = require("request");
request.get({
  time : true,
  url : 'https://www.bbc.com/',

},function(err, response){
  console.log('Request time in ms', response.timings);
});
```

Comment: just tested the code and works fine on. could you post the error log?

Comment: working for me as well. Maybe your `request` package version is old and doesn't support `timings` yet?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar this is what it shows : node app.js ,
Request time in ms undefined

Comment: try `console.log(err)` to see if there's any error

Comment: @Jenian I checked the version of request package its request@2.88.0 , its the latest version. I'm using node in VM can it be the reason?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar I tried its "null", I'm running Node in virtual machine Can it be the reason?

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar I posted the output of console.log(responce) in answers.

Comment: your response object does not contain `timings` for some reason. At this point not sure. You might be rigth, it could be the VM, but not sure how that could affect. Try on host machine if possible

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
const request = require("request");
request.get({
  time : true,
  url : 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip'

},function(err, response){
  console.log('Request time in ms', response.timings);
  console.log(response);
});
```

and this the output:

```
node app.js 
Request time in ms undefined
IncomingMessage {
  _readableState: 
   ReadableState {
     objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: true,
     ended: true,
     endEmitted: true,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     resumeScheduled: false,
     destroyed: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: false,
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { end: [ [Function: responseOnEnd], [Function], [Function] ],
     close: [ [Function], [Function] ],
     data: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Array],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        destroyed: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 67,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/ip HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: worldtimeapi.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/ip',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 511 },
  connection: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Array],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        destroyed: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 67,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/ip HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: worldtimeapi.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/ip',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 511 },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: true,
  headers: 
   { connection: 'close',
     server: 'Cowboy',
     date: 'Tue, 23 Apr 2019 08:15:33 GMT',
     'content-length': '284',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'cache-control': 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
     via: '1.1 vegur' },
  rawHeaders: 
   [ 'Connection',
     'close',
     'Server',
     'Cowboy',
     'Date',
     'Tue, 23 Apr 2019 08:15:33 GMT',
     'Content-Length',
     '284',
     'Content-Type',
     'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'Cache-Control',
     'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate',
     'Via',
     '1.1 vegur' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  upgrade: false,
  url: '',
  method: null,
  statusCode: 200,
  statusMessage: 'OK',
  client: 
   Socket {
     connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle: null,
     _parent: null,
     _host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        free: [Function: onFree],
        close: [Array],
        agentRemove: [Function: onRemove],
        drain: [Function: ondrain],
        error: [Function: socketErrorListener] },
     _eventsCount: 8,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState: 
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: true,
        ended: true,
        finished: true,
        destroyed: true,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: true,
        errorEmitted: false,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: false,
     allowHalfOpen: false,
     _bytesDispatched: 67,
     _sockname: null,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server: null,
     _server: null,
     parser: null,
     _httpMessage: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: 'GET /api/ip HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: worldtimeapi.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/ip',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _idleNext: null,
     _idlePrev: null,
     _idleTimeout: -1,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
     [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 511 },
  _consuming: true,
  _dumped: false,
  req: 
   ClientRequest {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Function],
        drain: [Function],
        prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     outputSize: 0,
     writable: true,
     _last: true,
     upgrading: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: false,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
     sendDate: false,
     _removedConnection: false,
     _removedContLen: false,
     _removedTE: false,
     _contentLength: 0,
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: true,
     _headerSent: true,
     socket: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 67,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 511 },
     connection: 
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 67,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 9,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 511 },
     _header: 'GET /api/ip HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: worldtimeapi.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
     _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     socketPath: undefined,
     timeout: undefined,
     method: 'GET',
     path: '/api/ip',
     _ended: true,
     res: [Circular],
     aborted: undefined,
     timeoutCb: null,
     upgradeOrConnect: false,
     parser: null,
     maxHeadersCount: null,
     [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: { host: [Array] } },
  request: 
   Request {
     domain: null,
     _events: 
      { error: [Function: bound ],
        complete: [Function: bound ],
        pipe: [Function],
        end: [Array],
        data: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 5,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     time: true,
     callback: [Function],
     method: 'GET',
     localAddress: undefined,
     pool: {},
     dests: [],
     __isRequestRequest: true,
     _callback: [Function],
     uri: 
      Url {
        protocol: 'http:',
        slashes: true,
        auth: null,
        host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
        port: 80,
        hostname: 'worldtimeapi.org',
        hash: null,
        search: null,
        query: null,
        pathname: '/api/ip',
        path: '/api/ip',
        href: 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip' },
     _redirectsFollowed: 0,
     maxRedirects: 10,
     followRedirect: true,
     followAllRedirects: false,
     redirects: [],
     headers: {},
     setHost: true,
     originalCookieHeader: undefined,
     _disableCookies: true,
     _jar: undefined,
     port: 80,
     host: 'worldtimeapi.org',
     clientErrorHandler: [Function],
     _parserErrorHandler: [Function],
     path: '/api/ip',
     httpModule: 
      { _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
        METHODS: [Array],
        STATUS_CODES: [Object],
        Agent: [Object],
        ClientRequest: [Object],
        globalAgent: [Object],
        IncomingMessage: [Object],
        OutgoingMessage: [Object],
        Server: [Object],
        ServerResponse: [Object],
        createServer: [Function: createServer],
        get: [Function: get],
        request: [Function: request] },
     agentClass: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object], defaultMaxSockets: Infinity },
     agent: 
      Agent {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: [Object],
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     _started: true,
     href: 'http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip',
     req: 
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: 0,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'GET /api/ip HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: worldtimeapi.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/ip',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     ntick: true,
     response: [Circular],
     _destdata: true,
     _ended: true,
     _callbackCalled: true },
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON],
  read: [Function],
  body: `'{"week_number":"17","utc_offset":"+04:30","unixtime":"1556007333","timezone":"Asia/Tehran","dst_until":"2019-09-21T19:30:00+00:00","dst_from":"2019-03-21T20:30:00+00:00","dst":true,"day_of_year":113,"day_of_week":2,"datetime":"2019-04-23T12:45:33.239417+04:30","abbreviation":"+0430"}' }`
```